# Django Auto UUID in Model not unique

Tags: django, django-models

Not sure if this is a bug in Django, or it just doesn't support what I'm trying to do (or how i'm doing it).

A snippet of my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, related_name='profile'
    login_hash = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    ...
```

As you see, i've set the default for `login_hash` to a call to `uuid.uuid4()`

works fine... however, multiple calls to the UserProfile (creating new users quickly, even seemingly a few minutes, but i've not an official time) will result in the same `login_hash` for multiple users.

It appears that django (i'm on 1.7.4) is caching the result of `uuid4()` for some period of time.  not good for what i'm trying to do.

SOLUTION:
that i'm using.  I've simply set an 'on insert' trigger on the database, so that when i insert a new record, the database generates the UUID, but only on inserts/new records.

**Is there a way to do it within django so that i can keep it database agnostic?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> works fine... however, multiple calls to the UserProfile (creating new users quickly, even seemingly a few minutes, but i've not an official time) will result in the same login_hash for multiple users.

As the code is currently written you're calling `uuid.uuid4()` at the point `UserProfile` is imported. It'll be called once and the resulting value will be the default for all new creations.

What you instead what to do is pass a *callable* as the default. Like so: `default=uuid.uuid4`.

Also, for `CharField` I'd strongly suggest not allowing `NULL` values as well as blank values. It's also not clear if you really do want to allow blank values for this field, but let's assume that you do. You should end up with this:

```
login_hash = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Comment: "slap forehead" ... of course... hate it when a couple braces mess things ups :) Thanks!